# Music files presenting as documents in FINDER search results

Tags: finder, music, search

Searching in Finder for a "pages" document.
Results displaying file documents designated as documents, including .pdf files, are actually linked in the search results to music files instead.
Result, Finder is displaying search results with no value as cannot open the so-named document because it opens a music file istead.
Any ideas as to what the cause may be?

For example, this file, "02 Room Gen Info Folders 01-2015.pages" connects to a music file.

Comment: "connects to a music file"… If you use 'Reveal in Finder, what file does your 'room gen' point to & what does Finder think it is if you then Cmd/i [Get Info]?

Comment: in finder search results, there is no option for Reveal in Finder but there is a show enclosing folder option.  The result of that is the actual music file, it does not go to the actual document.  As is "Get Info" shows the music file info, not the original document.  I failed to indicate that I have two external drives with many files including all music files and think now perhaps that affects how finder looks for docs...? But I have not always had this problem even with the eHDs connected.

Comment: Ah, I had assumed you were using Spotlight, rather than 'Cmd/F'. I still thin you probably ought to let Spotlight rebuild, though. [Drop all drives into Spotlight's Privacy panel in system prefs, then remove again] See https://support.apple.com/HT201716

Comment: I had not heard of rebuidling spotlight index before so I will give that a try and see what results I get. I did a search for a doc in spotlight and it resulted with the same music file for a document.  So "rebuilding" may be the solution. Thanks.